# Не понять как работает Scanner в моём коде

Tags: java, scanner

Есть код

```java
public static int printInt() {
    Scanner print = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        return print.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Введено не число!\nВведите повторно:");
        return printInt();
    }
}
```

Когда введено не число, код из блока `catch` выполняется много раз,  пока не заполнится стек и не возникнет ошибка переполнения стека.

Не могу понять, почему `Scanner` берет значение, которое консоль сама же вывела, и не даёт возможности ввести число.

У меня есть решение, но мне не нравится, что там используется ненужная переменная.

```java
public static int printInt() {
    Scanner print = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        return print.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Введено не число!\nВведите повторно:");
        String t = print.nextLine(); // ненужная переменная
        return printInt();
    }
}
```

И подскажите решение, не использующее ненужные переменные.

Comment: Описанная проблема с переполнением стека НЕ воспроизводится _при ручном вводе_, так как при рекурсивном вызове `printInt` каждый раз создаётся новый экземпляр сканера, который будет _заново_ считывать содержимое потока ввода, а предыдущий неверный ввод будет считан в буфер сканера при предыдущем вызове.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, непохоже, что это дубликат

Comment: @NowhereMan мне показалось, что ТС изобрёл рекурсивную функцию как раз для того, чтобы побороть особенность считывания nextInt

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Разве что второй вариант кода больше подходит для забарывания этой особенности..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно как-то обработать некорректные данные, оставшиеся в потоке ввода/сканере после предыдущей попытки чтения целого числа `print.nextInt`, достаточно было бы прочитать их при помощи `print.next()`, не сохраняя в отдельную переменную:

```java
public static int printInt(){
    Scanner print = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        return print.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Введено не число, длина некорректного ввода: " 
            + print.next().length() + "\nВведите повторно:");
        return printInt();
    }
}
```

Также имело бы смысл проверять наличие требуемого типа данных в потоке ввода / сканере, а не ловить исключение:

```java
public static int printInt(){
    Scanner print = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (print.hasNextInt()) {
        return print.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Введено не число!\nВведите повторно.  Длина неверного ввода: " + print.next().length());
    return printInt();
}
```